# Does continuous differentiability at a point imply that the function is continuous at a neighborhood of that point?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

So as the title says... Say we have a function that is continuously differentiable at $0$. And we also know that there exists a monotonous decreasing series $x_n\rightarrow0$ such that $f(x_n)f(x_n+1)<0$ does that somehow imply continuity at neighborhood of $0$?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that $f$ is continuously differentiable at $0$ you are assuming that $f'$ is defined in a neighborhood of $0$. This implies that $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$ because differentiability implies continuity.